# Angular assign value to class with Function

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to assin json object to class with function in Angular.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor() {
    const user: any = {
      FirstName: 'Tom',
      LastName: 'Jack',
    };
    let newUser: User = user;
    this.name = newUser.getName();
  }
}

export class User {
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
  getName() {
    return this.FirstName + this.LastName;
  }
}
```

It will throw error **ERROR
Error: newUser.getName is not a function**

Here is Test Online.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m3hnaj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Casting in typescript doesn't work the same as other typesafe languages. Since you say `const user: any = ...`, user can be interpreted as any type.

You first need to create a real `User` object first by calling the constructor. One way to 'assign' properties to an instantiated class is using `Object.assign`.

With your example:

```js
constructor() {
    const user = Object.assign(new User(), {
        FirstName: 'Tom',
        LastName: 'Jack'
    })

    this.name = user.getName();
}
```

I would consider this the old way of doing things, with new language features you can now use [object deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to acheive *mostly* the same effect.